# How to search exact phrase in string field with ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search

I want to search "Marketing in social networks" inside documents. All together. But i continue getting results with words separated. i have the following DSL query:

```
{
    "fields": ["title"], 
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [{
                "match": {
                    "title": "SEO"
                }
            }],
            "must": [{
                "match": {
                    "content": {
                        "query": "Marketing in social networks",
                        "operator": "and"
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

I do not have documents that contain this phrase and title but i also get results(documents) with the words of the phrase to search splitted. I want a strict search. If there is not any document that have this phrase do not retrieve any document or only retrieve documents with that title.
Why **operator and** does not work?

Comment: "and" means give me documents which contain all these words. Use the "match_phrase" query as mentioned in answer below. It will give you correct results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can you try like below using type phrase. See [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/phrase-matching.html) it says,

> query first analyzes the query string to produce a list of terms. It
>   then searches for all the terms, but keeps only documents that contain
>   all of the search terms, in the same positions relative to each other

```
{
    "fields": ["title"], 
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [{
                "match": {
                    "title": "SEO"
                }
            }],
            "must": [{
                "match": {
                    "content": {
                        "query": "Marketing in social networks",
                        "type":  "phrase"
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

P.S: I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Ok, "type": "phrase" seems to work well. Later i will test it deeply.

Comment: @XairoMartínez meanwhile you could accept the answer :-)

Answer (score 6):

First answer is good but for ES v5 using `"type":"phrase"` will return `[WARN ][org.elasticsearch.deprecation.common.ParseField] Deprecated field [type] used, replaced by [match_phrase and match_phrase_prefix query]` in the headers
So correct query should contain [match_phrase](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html):

```
 {
    "fields": ["title"], 
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [{
                "match": {
                    "title": "SEO"
                }
            }],
            "must": [{
                "match_phrase": {
                    "content": {
                        "query": "Marketing in social networks"
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```