# Exact phrase match in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, phrase

I'm trying to achieve exact search by phrase in Elastic, using my existing index (full-text). When user is searching, say, "Sanity Testing", the result should bring all the docs with "Sanity Testing" (case-insensitive), but not "Sanity tested".

My mapping:

```
{
  "doc": {
    "properties": {
      "file": {
        "type": "attachment",
        "path": "full",
        "fields": {
          "file": {
            "type": "string",
            "term_vector":"with_positions_offsets",
            "analyzer":"o3analyzer",
            "store": true
          },
        "title" : {"store" : "yes"},
        "date" : {"store" : "yes"},
        "keywords" : {"store" : "yes"},
        "content_type" : {"store" : "yes"},
        "content_length" : {"store" : "yes"},
        "language" : {"store" : "yes"}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As I understand, there's a way to add another index with "raw" analyzer, but I'm not sure this will work due to the need to search as case-insensitive. And also I don't want to rebuild indexes, as there are hundreds machines with tons of documents already indexed, so it may take ages.

Is there a way to run such a query? I'm now trying to search using the following query:

```
{
  query: {
    match_phrase: {
      file: "Sanity Testing"
    }
}
```

and it brings me both "Sanity Testing" and "Sanity Tested".

Any help appreciated!

Comment: can you post the settings of `o3analyzer`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39931006/how-to-search-exact-phrase-in-string-field-with-elasticsearch/39933760#39933760